# Idris pattern matching on successor (next value)

Tags: functional-programming, pattern-matching, idris

On the following function I'm pattern matching on the Successor of k on (S k)

```
vectTake : (n : Nat) -> Vect (n + m) a -> Vect n a
vectTake Z xs = []
vectTake (S k) (x :: xs) = x :: vectTake k xs
```

Is it possible to use that value on the body of the function if needed?

Another solution would be match on k and use the antecessor of k on the body function, so that just another form of solving the same problem or this kind of pattern matching provides any other advantages that I could not see?

Comment: i'm not sure what you mean. you're using `k` already, and if you change the signature (and functionality) a bit, you can use `S k` ... `vectTake (S k) (x :: xs) = (S k) :: vectTake k xs`

Comment: perhaps you mean named patterns `vectTake count@(S k) (x :: xs) = count :: vectTake k xs`

Comment: @JoelB thanks for your answer, both of them solve what I meant when I asked "Is it possible to use that value on the body of the function if needed?" And was great you reminded me about the naming feature Let me try to explain the second question better, could we do something like: 
`vectTake k (x :: xs) = x :: vectTake (pred k) xs` ?
If yes, what is the advantage on pattern matching in `(S k)` instead of `k`? –

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question ...

The (primitive) definition of `Nat` is

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat
```

We can match on:

- an arbitrary value using `k`
- the constructors. Here that's `Z` or `S k` . Of course `S k` would bind a different value to `k` than if we pattern matched on just `k`

Once you have matched on a value, you can do all the things you can normally do with a `Nat`, including constructing the successor using `S`, so if you wanted to match on `S k` and use it in a function, you could just

```
...
vectTake (S k) (x :: xs) = (S k) :: vectTake k xs
```

though here I've changed the meaning of your function to illustrate my point. In this example, you could also use a *named pattern*

```
...
vectTake count@(S k) (x :: xs) = count :: vectTake k xs
```

For your second question ...

By `pred k` I assume you mean predecessor not predicate. If so, you can do integer operations on `Nat` including `k - 1`, so, returning to the original definition of `vecTake`

```
...
vectTake k (x :: xs) = x :: vectTake (k - 1) xs
```

Note that this relies on the match for `Z` coming first, else you'll end up doing `Z - 1` which won't compile.

As for which is better out of matching on `Z` and `S k` or `Z` and `k`, I can't think of any objective reason why one's better than the other. Perhaps performance comes into it in some cases but I can't help you there. I'd mostly use the constructor patterns cos people will be used to seeing that, but I'm sure there will be cases where other styles are warranted.